# Design a layout in android

Tags: android, layout, imageview, spinner

What i want in my activity layout is 
2 spinners one after another
on the right or left side of spinner i want an imageview
and below the spinner i am adding various edittext and texviews.

I tried with linear layout and also relative layout not getting the desired result.

which layout should i use?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9" 
      android:entries="@array/category"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have some schema / sketch of what you're trying to achieve? LinearLayout seems to me the best choice, but it would be great if we could see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, can you post the whole XML layout? You're missing at least closing tags for RelativeLayout and root ScrollLayout. Are there any other views before ending tags?

Comment: my main problem is simply want imageview and spinner on the same horizontal line.....i.e imageview on the right of spinner...

Answer (score 0):

you should do following:

```
1) take linear layout with horizontal orientation.

2) put image view and spinner in it...and give the weight for both according to ratio of 10.

3) Same thing for another spinner and imageview.

4) And finally you have added editext below spinner in vertical layout.
```

You can use this and get your solution:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am doing as u said getting for vertical layout"This LinearLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)"

Comment: But have you get proper setting for spinner and image using weight??

Comment: post your screen shot here so i can give you proper solution

Comment: what i want is another spinner below it and rest of the edittext in horizontal oriental only